# Postgres on OSX - "ERROR: extension "adminpack" already exists"

Tags: macos, postgresql, pgadmin

using: 
pgAdmin3 (1.22.2) 
OSX (Sierra 10.12.4) 
postgres 9.6

When I am in pgAdmin, and I delete a test db catalog, I am prompted with this message:

`"server lacks instrumentation"`

The Guru hint appears with a 'FixIt' button.

When I click the 'FixIt' button I get the following error:

`"ERROR: extension "adminpack" already exists"`

I initially installed postgres with homebrew, but later completely uninstalled (including removing plist files) then re-installed with [postgresapp](https://postgresapp.com/)

any ideas on why this is happening/how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few suggestions:

- Make sure you've added `export PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:$PATH"` to your `.bash_profile`.
- Try pgAdmin 4 and see whether the behavior persists.

Comment: This fixed it! (modify .bash_profile) then close & restart pgAdmin3 - thanks!

Comment: congrats on your Teacher badge! :)

Comment: Glad it worked. Postgres.app is ridiculously simple to deploy/run compared to Postgres under Homebrew.